# How to send data from textbox to table field in access

Tags: ms-access

[image: Call Sheet]

Question How do I send information from text54 to the table view below field name notes.
What would be the code.

Comment: Per the close reasons, questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OnClick event of the Add Note button:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
set rec = db.OpenRecordSet ("Select * from YourTableName")

rec.AddNew
rec("Notes") = "" & Me!Text54 & ""
rec.Update

rec.Close
db.Close
```

You may have to tinker with the rec("Notes") line, it may need to be Me!text54.Text or Me!Text54.Value, I can't remember.

Oh, and once you've added the record, you'll probably have to refresh that table view so it shows up.  I can't tell if it's a subform or whatever so I can't tell you exactly how to do it.

Comment: is not a subform but let me try this code I let you know the result

Comment: I have a problem it told me something about the compiler

Comment: I have a nasty error telling me compile error user-defined type not defined

Comment: Please either write out the exact verbage or attach a screen shot to your original post.  Gotta split for a few hours, but I can check it out when I get back.  The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is you're missing a reference.